# Star graph second-smallest eigenvalue

Tags: graph-theory

> Prove that the star graph $K_{1,n-1}$ on $n$ vertices has $\lambda_2 = 1$, where $\lambda_2$ is the second-smallest eigenvalue of its' Laplacian.

Is it true for all trees?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The path on $4$ vertices is known to have (Laplacian) eigenvalues $2-2\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{4}\right)$ for $k\in\{0,1,2,3\}$.

The second smallest eigenvalue is $2-\sqrt{2}\neq 1$. In fact none of the eigenvalues are $1$.

Comment: But the star graph isn't a path....?

Comment: The question you asked is if $\lambda_2 = 1$ was true "for all trees".

Answer (score 1):

You can say something about trees on at least 3 vertices with $\lambda_2=1$.

In particular if your graph T is a tree on at least 3 vertices, then $\lambda_2=1$ if and only if T is a star